# Number of roots and Rouché's Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, roots

Given a polynomial $p(z)=z^4 +6z+3$, I want to show that it has exactly one root $z_1$ with $|z_1|<1$.

I am pretty sure it will be easy to show this using Rouché's Theorem. Using this I would have to find a function $f(z)$ with $\lvert f(z)-p(z)\rvert < \lvert f(z)\rvert\hspace{1cm} \forall z\in \partial S_1(0)$ where $S_1(0)$ is the unit circe around zero.

However, I did not have success finding a polynomial agreeing with this condition...

Comment: Easiest is to use one of the terms appearing in $p$. What term has a large modulus on $\lvert z\rvert = 1$, and only one zero in the disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(z)=6z$ and $g(z)=z^4+6z+3$. Clearly
$$
6=6|z|=|f(z)|>4= |z^4|+3\ge |z^4+3|=|f(z)-g(z)|,
$$
when $|z|=1$, and thus
$$
f(z)=6z \quad\text{and}\quad f(z)=z^4+6z+3,
$$
have the same number of roots in the open unit disk $D$ by virtue of Rouche's Theorem, i.e., both have exactly one root in $D$.